# OPENAI API Create Image Response from openai.createImage() giving errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, api, openai-api

I have a simple react app to generate images using openai api as follows.

`

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

function App() {
  const [userPrompt, setUserPrompt] = useState("")
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("")

  const generateImage = async () => {
    const imageParameters = {
      prompt: userPrompt,
      n:1,
      size: "256x256",
    }
    const response = await openai.createImage(imageParameters);
    const urlData = response.data.data[0].url;
    console.log("urlData =",urlData);
    setImageUrl(urlData);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        imageUrl
          ? <img src={imageUrl} className="image" alt="ai thing" />
          : <img src={logo} className="image" alt="logo" />
      }
      <p>Generate a unique image using DALL·E</p>
      <p>What do you want to see?</p>
      <input
        placeholder='A sunset on the Sydney Opera House'
        onChange={(e) => setUserPrompt(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => generateImage()}>Generate</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

The API KEY is inside .env file and is correct. However, when I click on generate button, it throws error on console like below:
[image: Errors: Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent", Post https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations 401, Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with createError .js: 16 status code 401]

I tried to create a react-app using DALL-E API to generate images using this [guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-react-app-using-dall-e-api-bd15d5d67b31). I am not able to receive (image) a response message after api call/request is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an ES6 NodeJs example that works and saves a PNG file. To get it to work add "type": "module", on top of your package.json. The request to the OpenAi returns you an array of urls to the png files. The "n" in the createImage is the number of the images in the array.

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import http from "https"; // or 'https' for https:// URLs
import fs from "fs";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const response = await openai.createImage({
  prompt: "A cute baby sea otter",
  n: 1,
  size: "1024x1024",
});

const file = fs.createWriteStream("test.png");
const request = http.get(response.data.data[0].url, function (response) {
  response.pipe(file);
  file.on("finish", () => {
    file.close();
    console.log("Download Done!");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap this call to createImage() within a try/catch and print the error in your catch block

> const response = await openai.createImage(imageParameters);